# openquery deferred prepare could not be completed during deployment of stored proc

Tags: sql-server

I am attempting to deploy a stored proc to a certain environment.  The stored proc has some OPENQUERY calls to another (source) server.  That source server has been set up as a linked server in the target server in the desired environment.  I am experiencing the following error during the deployment of the stored proc, which occurs in one of the calls:

```
Deferred prepare could not be completed.
```

This error is occurring during a call to a table that doesn't exist yet in the source server.  The error does not occur during calls to tables that do exist in the source server.

Does this imply that all called tables must already exist during the stored proc deployment?

Comment: What do you mean by "deployment" here?

Comment: I mean during the execution of the CREATE PROCEDURE statement (for the stored proc in question).  I do all of my deployments out of a DB project in Visual Studio, if it matters.

Comment: The concept of referencing an object that doesn't exist is known as deferred name resolution. This works well most of the time but when using a link server this does not happen. See this older question on this topic. https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/148069/44761 I also just tried creating a procedure with a linked server to a non-existent table and it failed.